# C++ command line debug argument

Tags: c++, c, debugging, command-line

How can I change the value of a boolean macro when I run my program through the command line? For instance, suppose I have the following macro in my cpp file, call it MyCpp.cpp

```
#define DEBUG 1
```

How can I change this when I run my program? through the command line:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -o MyCpp MyCpp.cpp
```

I am pretty sure you specify some kind of command line option, does this ring any bells?
Also, I do NOT want to use `argv[]`

Comment: Note that `MyCpp.cpp` must be one of the worst filenames I've ever seen. I bet it contains a `class Class` and a `struct struct_`, probably called from `void myfunction()`.

Comment: No, it contains `MyClass` and `MyStruct`, which are wrappers around `Class` and `Struct` in `Cpp.cpp`. :)

Comment: Do you want to change the value at *compile* time, or *execution* time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, change your source code:

```
#ifndef DEBUG
#  define DEBUG 1
#endif
```

Now you can say on the command line:

```sh
g++ -Wall -Wextra -o MyCpp MyCpp.cpp -DDEBUG=5
#                                    ^^^^^^^^^
```

The command line argument `-DFOO=bar` has the same effect as putting `#define FOO bar` in your source code; you need the `#ifndef` guard to avoid an illegal redefinition of the macro.

---

Sometimes people use an auxiliary macro to *prevent* the definition of another macro:

```
#ifndef SUPPRESS_FOO
#  define FOO
#endif

// ... later

#ifdef FOO
// ...
#endif
```

Now say `-DSUPPRESS_FOO` to *not* define `FOO` in the code...

Comment: You're typing too fast. At least this time, I saw it before I was finished.

Comment: does this give my macro the value of 5?

Comment: This isn't actually going to change the value every time you _run_ the app through the command line, but every time you _build_ the app. I think the latter is what the OP actually wants, but the former is what the introductory sentence to the question says…

Comment: @abarnert: That's true, but I gathered from the use of macros that the OP is after a modifiable compile-time value... if not, she's invited to clarify!

Comment: Yeah, as I said, I think the latter is what the OP actually wants… but just in case, I also gave a +1 to David Hammen, who gave the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I change the value of a boolean macro when I run my program through the command line?

As it stands, you can't. You are using a preprocessor symbol so the decision as to whether debug information should be printed is a compile time decision. You are going to have to change that compile-time DEBUG symbol to a run-time variable that you set by parsing the command line, via some configuration file read in at run time, or both.

Parsing the command line isn't that hard. There are plenty of low-level C-style tools to help you do that. Boost has a much more powerful C++ based scheme. The trick then is to change those compile-time debug decisions to run-time decisions. At the simplest, it's not that hard: Just replace that DEBUG preprocessor symbol with a global variable. You can get quite a bit more sophisticated than this of course. Eventually you'll have a configurable logging system. Boost has that, too.

Comment: This answers the question as asked by the OP, rather than what it seems like the OP probably wants. Either this or Kerrek SB's answer is probably right, but I'm not sure which, so +1 to both.

Answer (score 0):

Please note the following. If you have in your c/cpp file or one of your included header files:

```
#define DEBUG 1
```

then you cannot modify this definition using the command line of the compiler (makefile). There is simply no chance. The cpp file will simply overwrite the command line setting.